# How to JButton Toggle and Then Show JPasswordField

Tags: java, performance, swing, button

So I want to make a panel where two buttons will be presented and if one button is toggled then a password text area will show below it.

here is my code
I don't know where i messed p

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
// import javax.swing.event.*;

public class SelectShowPower extends JPanel {
    private JToggleButton teacher;
    private JButton student;
    private JPasswordField password;

    public SelectShowPower() {
        //construct components
        teacher = new JToggleButton ("Teacher");
        student = new JButton ("Student");
        password = new JPasswordField (5);

        //adjust size and set layout
        setPreferredSize (new Dimension (312, 143));
        setLayout (null);

        //add components
        add (teacher);
        add (student);

        //set component bounds (only needed by Absolute Positioning)
        teacher.setBounds (25, 35, 115, 40);
        student.setBounds (165, 35, 115, 40);
        password.setBounds (25, 80, 255, 25);

        String passText = new String(password.getPassword());


        teacher.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent teacher) {
                if(teacher.getModel().isPressed())
                {
                    add (password);
                    if (passText == "admin")
                        {
                            password.setVisible (true);
                        }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Select Show Power");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add (new SelectShowPower());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible (true);
        
    }
}
```

I want to get a solution of how to add this system in my code?

Comment: 1) the code doesn't compile 2) add some debug code to verify that your if condition is being executed. 3) Don't use "==" for String comparison. Instead you should use the `equals(...)` method.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: unrelated: null layout (and any hard-coded sizing/positioning) is __wrong__! Instead use a layoutManager that suits your needs

Answer (score 0):

Use `password.setEchoChar((char) 0);` to show the password and `password.setEchoChar('*');` to hide it again.

Also, to retrieve the password String from the jpasswordfield, use:

```
char[] pwd = password.getPassword();
//Convert the password to a string
String passwordString = new String(pwd);
```